# Yosemite installation failure: hard drive can't be repaired

Tags: macos, install

I tried to upgrade from Mac OS X 10.7 to OS X 10.10.3. During the install the process got stuck and didn't finish.
After booting to Recovery Mode I tried to make an image of the Macintosh HD volume onto an external drive in the hope to recover all my files.

System specs:

MacBook Pro 2011 13 inch 8 GB RAM 750 GB storage 250 GB used.
No backup.

Error messages:

Comment: Did you already try to boot to Recovery or Internet Recovery Mode to repair your system drive?

Comment: You should really try to put some more effort and tell us what you did, and where do you get the error.

Comment: @klanomath yesterday tried to install OSX 10.10.3 on a mac book pro mid 2011. installation starts and stucks immediately. holding cmd+L it said it could not find the keychain and hard drive failure. tried to restart holding shift would not work. boot to recovery worked verified disk, partition appears OK. reairing disk partition appears OK. Still wont install.

Comment: @matteo hope the comment above helps more

Comment: @klanomath trying to make an new image through disk utilities after booting into recovery failed. Stoped at Reading cosutmer (apple_HFS : 5)... (Output/input error).

Comment: @Sisu Is "cosutmer" just a spelling error or is it the name of your main disk? What did you try to achieve by holding Cmd-L? Is ist a special shortcut in the installer app? What was the previous OS on your Mac? What kind of new image did you try to make? Please add the informations to  your question by editing it.

Comment: @klanomath sorry Spelling mistake. Press Cmd-L to See what is happening while install. Was recommended to me. Did take me anywhere.

Comment: @klanomath trying to get to all my files but I can't restart the old drive it tells me he can not gather enough information.

Comment: @Sisu Do you have a camera to take (screen)shots and a second Mac to post them here? If so take some shots of the error messages and post them here. Additionally boot to [Recovery or Internet Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314), open Terminal.app and enter `diskutil list` and add the output by editing your question here. Please also open Disk Utility in Recovery Mode and verify the disk and post the result (screenshot).

Comment: @klanomath where an I find the terminal app. Making pictures right now. Thanks

Comment: @Sisu After booting to Recovery Mode open "Utilities" in the menubar. I think the 3rd entry is Terminal.app

Comment: @klanomath while I was reproducing all error messages to make screenshots, disk utilities repaired something with the boot. I could restard old OS 10.7 and backing up for the next 6 hr. Problem one fixed. will retry to install 10.10.3 after backing up all data. any last advice? thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Sisu Always back before upgrading ;-). How do you upgrade to Yosemite? Do you use an installer thumb drive or a downloaded OS X installer in the /Applications folder?

Comment: @klanomath I downloaded OS X installed in the app folder. I am so happy I hadn't to learn this lesson the hard way. Thanks for the support during this nerve wrecking experience :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Target Disk Mode. Instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201462)

With this you can turn your Mac into an hard drive. Just boot to TDM and connect your Mac and another Mac using a thunderbolt cable. You should then find the disk in finder.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting in Single user mode. Hold cmd+s during restart.

Let it finish and type

```
fsch -fy
```

and let it run, and observe results of the disk repair attempt.

You’ll get a note at the end that says your drive is OK, or that it needs fixing. If it needs fixing, run the command again, until you get a notice that your drive appears to be OK. Once that happens, simply type:

```
reboot
```